# Strategy pattern and iterator on all algorithms

Tags: java, strategy-pattern

I have a list of algorithms that I want to run on an image for denoise it.   I have several different algorithms for denoising my pics. Say I have denoise_1 and denoise_2 and denoise_3. But in the future I will need to add denoise_4, validation_four, etc.

I need ALL of the denoise to run on the picture, even the new ones when they get added.

In addition : if I add another algorithm I must notify the system.

I am thinking about using strategy and observer patterns, but I have not found an acceptable solution.

Is this the right way??

I apologize if for opening a new thread, I found a similar thread but I did not understand the solution.

Comment: You should share the other thread so that others can clarify then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes strategy is fine:
Let all denoise Algorithm implement a common Interface.

Comment: ok,but my problems are : 

First : how i can use "all" denoise algorithms on a picture??the strategy tell that i can use one,selected at run time . 

Second : in observer pattern, who observe who??

Third : how i notify the system for adding new algorithm??

Many thank

Comment: 1. in a loop; 2. this is another question, 3. algos are typically initialited at startup, no need to add an denoiser at runtime

Comment: so for the first question a need a list of algorithms to execute in a method (for ex method compare) ??

for second and third I'm sorry but I did not understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

Say all your algorithms implement the same `DenoiseAlgorithm`. Simply place all your algorithms in a `List<DenoiseAlgorithm>` and run them one by one by iterating over that list.

If the list is global, adding new algorithm (at the beginning or the end, you decide) has global effect on the whole system.

Also consider [chain-of-responsibility](/questions/tagged/chain-of-responsibility) pattern.

Comment: ok, first of all thanks to alexWien and to Tomasz Nurkiewicz. 

then...

creating a list of algorithms i do not need to use the observer and I do not need to notify anything, right?